# 2021 all Russian olympiad

Tags: graph-theory, contest-math

In the country there're $N$ cities and some pairs of cities are connected by two-way airlines (each pair with no more than one). Every airline belongs to one of $k$ companies. It turns out that it's possible to get to any city from any other, but it fails when we delete all airlines belonging to any one of the companies. What is the maximum possible number of airlines in the country ?

Comment: what have you tried?

Answer (score 1):

HINT: A path on $N$ vertices, with each of the $N-1$ edges in the path belonging to a different airline, shows that there is an instance with $k=N-1$ airlines.

Now it is left to show that $k=N$ airlines is impossible. Indeed, assume that there are $N$ airlines. Then the available flights on the $N$ cities must form a connected graph with at least $N$ edges. So let $T$ be any $N-1$ flights that form a spanning tree of the cities. There is at least one of the $N$ airline does not have any of those $N-1$ flights on $T$.